# Creating a Digital Twin Project with ROS1

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, ur5

I'm currently working on a digital twin project using ROS Melodic, aiming to create a virtual replica of a physical UR5 robot equipped with ToF sensors. The objective is to sensors in Gazebo so that the sensors perceive the robot model just as they would in real life.

The thing I am stuck on is how to move the robot model directly using joint states received from RTDE form the real robot, without any controllers in-between, just simply write the joint states.

The reason I am using Gazebo is because the sensors need to be simulated. The goal is to get readings form the simulated sensors as close as possible to the real sensors on the real robot.

Any help regarding how to do directly move the robot model in gazebo using the real joint data would be really appreciated.
Also, if there are any better programs to do this then I am also open to suggestions.

Thank you for any support and expertise!